# Thread-safe CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, multithreading, observablecollection, caliburn.micro, collectionviewsource

I've been using Caliburn.Micro's BindableCollection to render the data for Telerik RadGridView and it's thread-safe which means I can update the collection from the non-UI thread.

Now what I am trying to do is to filter the datagrid using a predicate. The nature thought is to use CollectionViewSource so that my underlying data does not change and I can control the CollectionViewSource's view by applying predicate on it. The issue is CollectionViewSource is not thread-safe and will throw if the source updated from non-UI thread.

Here below is the XAML and view model.

**XAML:**

```
        <controls:RadGridView Grid.Column="2"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          behaviours:RadGridViewExtensions.RowDoubleClick="OpenProgram"
                          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                          CanUserInsertRows="False"
                          DataContext="{Binding ContractHeadersCollectionView}"
                          IsReadOnly="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                          RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContractHeader}"
                          SelectionMode="Single"/>
```

**View Model:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="PortfolioViewModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public PortfolioViewModel()
    {
        this.ContractHeaders = new BindableCollection<ContractHeaderViewModel>();
        this.ContractHeadersCollectionView = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = ContractHeaders };
    }

    public CollectionViewSource ContractHeadersCollectionView { get; private set; }
```

The questions are:

1. Does Calibun.Micro provide a thread-safe CollectionViewSource equivalent?
2. If not, what's the option if I don't want marshal the calls to update BindableCollection to the UI thread?

Thanks for any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: And why dont you want to marshal calls? Thats what people do when they modify UI.

Comment: We don't have to until this filtered view come into play, and that's why it is not in the first place. Also we want to overcome some overhead when doing the unit testing - don't need to worry about providing synchronisation context and marshalling.

Comment: You have to marshal calls one way or another when you work with UI from another thread. There is no workaround afaik. You may hide the marshaling inside of implementation of some "thread safe" collection view, but its still there. As for if the framework you use have such class, i think you'd be better asking it on it's forums

Answer (score 0):

You need to marshal calls to the UI thread. Caliburn.Micro provides `Execute.OnUiThread` in Caliburn.Micro for marshalling calls to the UI Thread.